# Same account, multiple applications

Tags: android

I am developing an SDK which multiple applications will use. This SDK should login to the user's account and will provide the application with server interaction works. My problem is that I want to share this user's account between these applications. So there should be a mechanism in which applications will first look up the account if it exists, they will use it, if not, they will create it. But I am having technical challenges.

I looked up android's custom accounts so that the account credentials could be stored there. But I am not sure if it is possible there. First, is it possible to see if an account under a certain type exists? Second, is it possible for an application to use an account which another application created? For example, google games is doing exactly this functionality. Any game can login with user's google game account. But I need to do this without installing a third-party service on user's device.

Generally, if you have anything helpful to solve this situation, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like Firebase authentication?

Comment: @Kuffs that is one interesting solution thanks. But I am curious, how these solution work exactly?

Comment: Should the client install firebase service separately? I think I read that firebase SDK will call firebase service for authentication

Comment: Full instructions are on the site. Just add the library to your app. No additional downloads required. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deep in the explained situation, I got my answer

- First, yes it is possible to see if there exist an account under an specific name. This name can be different from the application's URI.
- Second, it is possible to use an account which another application has been created.

So in the SDK, I can first lookup a contracted account name which there will be an stored token. If it exists, the SDK will store it in the shared preferences. If it does not exist, the SDK will create the token using the user's credentials. This way, other applications can use this account and if the application which created the account has been uninstalled, the next application which runs, will recreate the token in accounts from its shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for a solution on the device you can use a content provider to share data between the two apps.

Comment: This is good, but there is a problem. Which app should provide the content? What happens when the provider app has been uninstalled? Maybe getting the list of all contents in the device and search for content names which is in a certain format will solve this but this is some kind of messy I think. I mean any other app can create that format and there will be security problems